# Bootstrap 1st column hide, 2nd column full size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <div class="panel panel-success">
                 <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <div class="panel panel-success">
                 <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <div class="panel panel-success">
                 <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                   <div class="panel-heading">Next Gameday</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Dummy text</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                   <div class="panel-heading">Next Gameday</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Dummy text</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want to hide the right column and do expand the left column, when the website is viewd in smartphones or so. I am already using @media queries in my css, but i dont know how to expand the left column to fullscreen.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my (sometimes) bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Change `col-xs-9 col-sm-9` to `col-xs-12 col-sm-12`. You can also remove the `col-xs-3` and `col-sm-3` classes from your `hidden-xs hidden-sm` element as well as these are unnecessary.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9"> ... </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm"> ... </div>
```

You'd benefit from reading through Bootstrap's [Grid System documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

For what it's worth, you can drop the `col-sm-*` and `col-lg-*` classes altogether if they're identical to your `col-xs-*` and `col-md-*` classes.

Comment: You don't need `col-sm-12` either if you are using `col-xs-12`. Same for `col-lg-3`

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn indeed, this is why I advised OP to read the relevant documentation.

Comment: Well... that anweser was quite simple.. thank you very much. In german there is an old saying "Man sieht den Wald vor lauter Bäumen nicht". :D